# How do I make train and test set the same size using bag of words

Tags: tensorflow, keras, nlp, token, vectorization

I want to use bag of words to train a regression model. But, I do not want to have information leak between my train and test sets. So, that means I need to create a word vector on the train set separate from my test set. I ran this code

```
def bow (tokens, data):
    tokens = tokens.apply(nltk.word_tokenize)
    cvec = CountVectorizer(min_df = .01, max_df = .95, ngram_range=(1,2), tokenizer=lambda doc:doc, lowercase=False)
    cvec.fit(tokens)
    cvec_counts = cvec.transform(tokens)
    cvec_counts_bow = cvec_counts.toarray()
    vocab = cvec.get_feature_names()
    bow_model = pd.DataFrame(cvec_counts_bow, columns=vocab)
    return bow_model

X_train = bow(train['clean_text'], train)
X_test = bow(test['clean_text'], test)

vocab = list(X_train.columns)
```

But the shape of my data frames are X_train: (300, 730) and X_test (35, 1661)
There are more unique words in my test set than my train set -- because the train set is so small --- and the words do not match. There are words in X_train that are not in X_test and vice versa. I thought to create a vocab list from X_train then keep only the columns in X_test but that doesn't seem right.

How do I fit the vocabulary from the X_train onto X_test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looking like you create different vocabs for train and test sets.
You can try to move next code from bow function and create just one vocab which is based on train set. Also you don't need to use nltk.word_tokenize because CountVectorizer already have tokenizer:

```
cvec = CountVectorizer(min_df = .01, max_df = .95, ngram_range=(1,2), lowercase=False)
cvec.fit(train['clean_text'])
vocab = cvec.get_feature_names() 
print(vocab)
```

And then change bow function:

```
def bow (tokens, vocab, cvec):
    cvec_counts = cvec.transform(tokens)
    cvec_counts_bow = cvec_counts.toarray()
    bow_model = pd.DataFrame(cvec_counts_bow, columns=vocab)
    return bow_model

X_train = bow(train['clean_text'], vocab, cvec)
X_test = bow(test['clean_text'], vocab, cvec)
```

Or look at example how I did it.

Firstly, I create vocab using just train set. Also I use just more common words from this set and other set like `'<UNK>'`.

You can use next code for this:

```
 def create_vocab(all_tokens, vocab_size):   
     token_counts = Counter(all_tokens)   
     token_counts = token_counts.most_common()[:vocab_size]   
     vocab_list = ['<UNK>'] + [token for token, _ in token_counts]   
     return vocab_list
```

Than after creating vocab I use it for bag of words like there:

```
 def bag_of_words(tokens, vocab_list):
     result = [0] * len(vocab_list)
     for t in tokens:
       if t not in vocab_list:
         t = '<UNK>'
     result[vocab_list.index(t)] += 1
     return result
```

Using this code I create bag of words which include all words from my vocab (which was created using just train set) and `'<UNK>'` symbol for words which is not in my vocab.

There is an example how I run this code:

```
vocab_list = create_vocab(list(chain.from_iterable(tokens_train)), 5000)

bag_of_words_train = []
for token in tokens_train:
  bag_of_words_train.append(bag_of_words(token, vocab_list))

bag_of_words_test = []
for token in tokens_test:
  bag_of_words_test.append(bag_of_words(token, vocab_list))
```

Comment: @olesiaslavchnyk Thank you very much!!! I got the first option to run successfully but not the second with <UNK>. I must be doing something wrong -- my bag_of_words_train and bag_of_words_test are a series of 0s. Also, the vocab list is unigrams. How can I get bi-grams as well? I added

```
tokens_train = X_train['text'].apply(nltk.word_tokenize)
tokens_test = X_test['text'].apply(nltk.word_tokenize)
```

Comment: @KimS. You can add ngram_range=(1, 2) as a parameter of CountVectorizer for getting unigrams and bi-grams or ngram_range=(2, 2) for getting only bi-grams.

Also are you sure that your tokens_train and tokens_test created with nltk.word_tokenize the same as tokens in you vocab?
I believe that it would be better if you don't use  nltk.word_tokenize.

Comment: @olesiaslavchnyk I guess I am confused on how you created tokens_train. When I tried to run the code as is, I get an error that tokens_train doesn't exist. I started with "def create_vocab..." to the last line of code. Do you know what I am missing?